# snmp entry in log messages

Tags: logging, snmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduce SNMPd logging verbosity](https://serverfault.com/questions/310640/reduce-snmpd-logging-verbosity)

I have following 2 lines in my /var/log/messages

```
Jun 15 17:54:22 myserver8 snmpd[5380]: Connection from UDP: [10.10.11.67]:61784 
Jun 15 17:54:22 myserver8 snmpd[5380]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [10.10.11.67]:61784
```

Does it mean that my snmp is not configured correctly?

Comment: It means your snmpd is configured to log connections/traffic. Is that "correctly" configured for your environment? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems only snmp log, nothing to worried, please refers to http://raetsel.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/snmpd-filling-up-varlogmessages/

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect SNMP connections from this address? If not, than your server is not configured correctly.