# Reduce SNMPd logging verbosity

Tags: logging, snmpd

SNMPd on my CentOS systems is sending log messages to syslog every time it receives a query from my monitoring tools. Is there a way to lower the verbosity of SNMPd? It adds a lot of clutter to the logs.

```
Sep 12 13:05:40 myhost snmpd[7073]: Received SNMP packet(s) from UDP: [ipaddr]:42874
Sep 12 13:05:40 myhost snmpd[7073]: Connection from UDP: [ipaddr]:49272
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check the command that starts `snmpd` (possibly somewhere `/etc/rc.d/` - in Ubuntu it's `/etc/defaults/snmpd`) for the logging options:

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -g root 0.0.0.0'
```

Or find it in the `ps aux | grep snmpd` output.

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpcmd) gives the logging options:

> -Ls FACILITY
>
> Log messages via syslog, using the specified facility ('d' for LOG_DAEMON, 'u' for LOG_USER, or '0'-'7' for LOG_LOCAL0 through LOG_LOCAL7). 
>   There are also "upper case" versions of each of these options, which allow the corresponding logging mechanism to be restricted to certain priorities of message.
>
> For -LF and -LS the priority specification comes before the file or facility token. The priorities recognised are:

```
0 or ! for LOG_EMERG,
1 or a for LOG_ALERT,
2 or c for LOG_CRIT,
3 or e for LOG_ERR,
4 or w for LOG_WARNING,
5 or n for LOG_NOTICE,
6 or i for LOG_INFO, and
7 or d for LOG_DEBUG.
```

The default is fairly verbose (only 2 levels below debug):

> Normal output is (or will be!) logged at a priority level of LOG_NOTICE

If you're logging to syslog via LOG_DAEMON (-Lsd), you could reduce it to e.g. LOG_WARNING with `-LSwd`/`-LS4d`, or LOG_ERR with `-LSed`/`-LS3d`.

(Edited to put the options in the right order.)

Comment: I struggled to find the correct location on CentOS 6.5. It's not  `/etc/snmp/snmpd.options` nor is it `/etc/sysconfig/snmpd.options` but actually it is `/etc/sysconfig/snmpd`. The `ps aux | grep snmpd` was really useful to see if the changes were working.

Comment: In Debian using systemd it is wired in `/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service`, use `systemctl cat snmpd` and `systemctl edit snmpd` to *override* `[Service]ExecStart` only. `ExecStart` should be entered twice, the first time empty to clear the old (look for *systemd override vendor settings* feature)

Answer (score 20):

In order to set the minimum priority to LOG_WARNING, (which is what I usually use) simply change the argopt:

> -Lsd

to

> -LSwd

Which stands for:

- **S**: syslog, priority comes next
- **w**: (or **4**) log only warnings and more relevant messages
- **d**: use the LOG_DAEMON facility

As stated in the [man](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpcmd.html) (but actually missing a clear example):

> For -LF and -LS the priority specification comes before the file or facility token

Comment: Oops, I missed the order of priority/facility.

Answer (score 13):

> `dontLogTCPWrappersConnects`
>
> If the snmpd was compiled with TCP Wrapper support, it logs every connection made to the agent. This setting disables  the
>                 log messages for accepted connections. Denied connections will still be logged.

I.e. add `dontLogTCPWrappersConnects true` to snmpd.conf.

I'm puzzled why this log message is considered above LOG_DEBUG, for a monitoring service (and one that supports UDP) :-( .  `journalctl -o verbose` shows the message has PRIORITY=6 (INFO), which is the same as the normal startup messages for snmpd.

Comment: Appears to work as well as changing the logging level from notice to warn, but in a way that is more focused on the connection logging.

Comment: This worked best for me to remove logging for successful connection attempts, rather than narrowing the log criteria.

Answer (score 7):

I completely remove the "-Lsd" directive from the `/etc/sysconfig/snmpd.options` file in CentOS/Redhat installations, leaving a file that reads:

```
# snmpd command line options
OPTIONS="-Lf /dev/null -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -a"
```

Comment: does this completely stop all snmpd logs, or does it fall back to default logging?

Answer (score 6):

Including the standard (included in the default `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` file for CentOS 6.5) line worked for me to reduce the verbosity specifically with respect to TCP/UDP SNMP connection logging:

```
dontLogTCPWrappersConnects yes
```

Here is a more "verbose" excerpt from the default `snmp.conf` file:

```
# We do not want annoying "Connection from UDP: " messages in syslog.
# If the following option is commented out, snmpd will print each incoming
# connection, which can be useful for debugging.

dontLogTCPWrappersConnects yes
```

Answer (score -1):

on the raspberry pi / raspbian, the file location is

/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service

then you have to do a daemon-reload before restarting the snmpd service.

systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: You probably shouldn't edit that file directly, instead create an override file by running `systemctl edit snmpd.service` which brings up a blank file, add three lines 
    "[Service]\n
    ExecStart=\n
    ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd <whatever you want here>"
and save it.  The `systemctl edit` takes care of the `daemon-reload`